# real time notifications with Laravel backend and android FrontEnd

Tags: android, laravel-5.5, pusher

My application is simple just alot of posts and every post has many comments.
I want to notify users when a comment is posted with a real time notification   method.
I use laravel for backend and android for frontend , i found something   called pusher , is there any method better than pusher for my app ?
or this is the method to use now for my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pusher is a paid service the better option is **Firebase Push Notifications** which are really easy to use and free of cost for large amount of usage.

It also provide a lot of customization and easy to work with it.

Comment: ok thanks but i dont want to use firebase as a database or for notifications , so can you recommend another one , alot of people say that onesignal is good too

Comment: buddy you don't need to use firebase database as an backend for using firebase notifications.

Comment: oh i searched for it and i get it now i am still somehow new to these things but thanks